# Azure B2C App Insights logging: prevent passwords being logged

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, appinsights

How can we mask/hide password claim so the developers who are troubleshooting the journeys do not see users passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only hide PII when App Insights is in Production mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-application-insights-in-production

Comment: Following these instructions mean no logs will be recorded. How do we retain logs, but hide PII?

Comment: Exceptions are logged.

Comment: I've found the errors recorded in application insights to be essentially useless without the associated logs. You don't even know what step the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to mask/hide/encrypt from Application Insight for Azure B2C. However here are the following workarounds you could test with:

**Don't include claims with personal data.**

- Within Application insights technical profile AppInsights-Common, AppInsights-SignInRequest, AppInsights-UserSignUp and AppInsights-SignInComplete there should not be any claims transformation Input similar to *InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordTransformation"* or *Output claims OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="plaintextPassword" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"* or *InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim*

**Do not set the DeploymentMode to Development in production environments**

- Logs collect all claims sent to and from identity providers. You as
  the developer assume responsibility for any personal data collected
  in your Application Insights logs. These detailed logs are collected
  only when the policy is placed in DEVELOPER MODE. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-application-insights-in-production

Thanks

Comment: thank you, we do not have appinsights-common and other additional technical profiles. Just have the default setup. Any way to exclude password claims with the basic setup?